# example of uniformly most powerful test

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family, inference, neyman-pearson-lemma

let X be a single observation from the density $f(x;\theta)$ =$ \theta x^{\theta -1} I_{(0,1)}(x)$

is there a UMP size-$\alpha$ test for testing $H_0 :\theta \ge \frac{1}{2} $ V/S $ H_1 : \theta <  \frac{1}{2} $  ?

**Atempt** :for general solution let $ \theta_0 = \frac{1}{2} $

comparing $f(x;\theta)$ with the form $a(\theta)b(x)exp[c(\theta)d(x)]$ ,

we get $d(x) = log (x)$ and $ c(\theta ) = \theta -1 $ as monotone , increasing function in $\theta$ and therefor , critical region **C =[$(x) :log(x) > k$ ]** gives uniformly most powerful size - $\alpha $ test for testing

$H_0 :\theta \le  \theta_0 $ V/S $ H_1 : \theta >  \theta_0 $

so for testing $H_0 :\theta \ge \theta_0 $ V/S $ H_1 : \theta <  \theta_0 $ , just the inequality in the critical region will get reversed  i.e the critical region **C =[$(x) :log(x) < k$ ]**  gives uniformly most powerful size - $\alpha $ test such that $P_{\theta_0}[log(x) < k$ ] = $\alpha$ .

**is my logic correct   ?**

Comment: Well, to finish the test maybe you should define constant $k_{\alpha}$ also

Comment: @Lukasz_Grad  that ill do , is the rest correct ?